# Scrapy - only scraping domain namess

Tags: dns, scrapy, web-crawler

How can I implement scraping only domain names with Scrapy.

I am not interested in deep search of any domain.tld. My idea was only to use depth of 1 jump from index page of every domain - so direct links from homepage would be sufficient for links buffer.

I need as fast crawler as only can be.

I want to limit domains realm to .cz

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape every possible .cz website? Or do you have a list of URLs, but you want to limit it to only .cz?

Comment: I want to find as many .cz domains as only can be - I don't know of better way to do that. I am not interested in data only in hrefs pointing outside of current domain I am crawling so they can be crawled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DEPTH_LIMIT` parameter on `SETTINGS` to restrict the crawl to the depth you want.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=depth_limit

If you want only to go 1 jump deep, you should set `DEPTH_LIMIT=2` and select links using a `selector` or `link_extractor`.

Ex: 
`response.xpath('//a/@href').re(r'.*.example.com.*')`

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=link_extractor